# How to call script on tuple in shellbolt

Tags: java, python, shell, apache-storm

First day playing around with storm in Java so appreciate any help -- I'd like to call a Python script in a bolt in order to do some calculations. This Python script depends on numerical input which I hope to pass into this bolt. There is the `ShellBolt` class but all examples I can find just call a script without any arguments (in the constructor).

How can I call a Python script and pass in values dependent on the input tuple? Ideally, can I spawn a shell process from the `execute`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a closer look into `WordCountTopology` (ie, `splitsentence.py`) from storm-starter you can see that the Python script implements a class with a method that take a tuple as input. This is basically your `execute` method implemented in Python. Storm will call `process` for each incoming tuples to `execute`:

```
import storm

class SplitSentenceBolt(storm.BasicBolt):
    def process(self, tup):
        words = tup.values[0].split(" ")
        for word in words:
          storm.emit([word])

SplitSentenceBolt().run()
```

In the background, Storm forks a new Java `UNIXProcess` that execute the Pyhton script. You don't need to do anything by yourself. Storm handles it for you.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. I'm assuming the tuple could have elements of any type, so I could pass in tuples of lists as well? (all examples I have found so far seem to tuples of strings)

Comment: A tuple can have any number of attributes. And each attribute can be of any type, including lists.